# Groovy how to delegate certain methods to other class methods?

Tags: java, groovy

I'm very new to groovy, I wish I would like to do this.

Lets say I have a class called `App.groovy`.

```
class App
{
}
```

I have other class called `DelegateClass`, which has two methods:

```
edit
create
```

In other class, I need do this:

```
    //class Test
    def app = new App()
    app.editDetails()
    app.createDetails()
    app.editOtherDetails()
```

I want all methods start with `edit*` goes to `DelegateClass` `edit` method and the same for `create*` methods.

How can I do that?

Out of curiosity, is the same can be done in java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, say you have this delegate class:

```
class DelegateClass {
    String create( args ) {
        "create ${args.join(',')}"
    }

    String edit( args ) {
        "edit ${args.join(',')}"
    }
}
```

Then you could use `methodMissing` in your App class:

```
class App {
    DelegateClass delegate = new DelegateClass()

    def methodMissing( String name, args ) {
        if( name.startsWith( 'create' ) ) {
            delegate.create( args )
        }
        else if( name.startsWith( 'edit' ) ) {
            delegate.edit( args )
        }
    }
}
```

So all the following works:

```
def app = new App()
assert app.editDetails() == 'edit '
assert app.editDetails( 'foo' ) == 'edit foo'
assert app.editDetails( 'foo', 'bar' ) == 'edit foo,bar'
assert app.createDetails( 'tim' ) == 'create tim'
assert app.createOtherDetails() == 'create '
```

With java, there's no such thing as `methodMissing`, so you'd need to send strings describing the method to call to a centralised handler method, and have that call the method you want.